# transform rotate(-90deg) change left position

Tags: html, css

i have this problem with the rotation of a element.
this is what i done

```html
<div style="position:absolute;transform: rotate(-90deg)">12</div>
<div style="position:absolute;transform: rotate(-90deg)">1234</div>
<div style="position:absolute;transform:rotate(-90deg)">1234567</div>
<div style="position:absolute;transform:rotate(-90deg)">9876545</div>
<div style="position:absolute;transform:rotate(-90deg)">12345678910654</div>
```

why the position of div change by the string lenght??

Comment: Because the initial value for `transform-origin` is `50% 50% 0` …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `transform-origin` in your css:

```html
<div style="position:absolute;transform: rotate(90deg); 
transform-origin:bottom left;">12</div>
<div style="position:absolute;transform: rotate(90deg); 
transform-origin:bottom left;">1234</div>
<div style="position:absolute;transform:rotate(90deg); 
transform-origin:bottom left;">1234567</div>
<div style="position:absolute;transform:rotate(90deg); 
transform-origin:bottom left;">9876545</div>
<div style="position:absolute;transform:rotate(90deg); 
transform-origin:bottom left;">12345678910654</div>
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: eeeeexcellent!!